# Pegar tamanho da matriz com EQ() - Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Estou com um `html` que possui cinco elementos `div`.

Gostaria que me ajudassem de alguma forma a fazer um Get do tamanho desta matriz em Jquery.

Ex: com a função `eq()`, consige pegar um elemento da página, referenciada por matriz.
Se eu usar o seguinte código `$( "body" ).find( "div" ).eq( 2 ).css( "background-color","blue");`, a terceira `div` da matriz terá o fundo em azul.

Como pegar o valor total dessa matriz?

Comment: Já tentou `$( "body" ).find( "div" ).length`?

Comment: Por "valor total" não está claro se você quer o número de divs, ou um array com todos os divs dentro. Seja como for, minha resposta aponta o caminho.

Comment: @Sergio obrigado, Resolveu o problema!

Comment: @FranckCosta, ótimo! Deixei também uma resposta em baixo. Pode marcar como correta se foi essa a solução que procurava.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você quer saber quantos elementos/objetos essa matriz têm pode usar o [**.length**](http://api.jquery.com/length/) que lhe vai dar o numero de elementos no objeto jQuery.

```
var matriz = $( "body" ).find( "div" ).length;
```

Comment: foi desta maneira que utilizei e funcionou, agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score 4):

O que o jQuery retorna para `$( "body" ).find( "div" )` é um "objeto jQuery", que é muito similar a um array. Em muitos aspectos, pode ser tratado como se fosse um (por exemplo, possui propriedade `length` indicando quantos itens há dentro).

Mas se você quer um array puro, pode simplesmente usar:

```
var arrayDeDivs = $( "body" ).find( "div" ).get();
```

Answer (score 3):

Se o seu objetivo for aplicar algum estilo ao último `div` encontrado dentro do `body`, pode fazer isso usando o seletor jquery `:last`:

```
$( "body div:last" ).css( "background-color","blue");
```

ou

```
$( "body div" ).last().css( "background-color","blue");
```

Acabei de descobrir que `eq` pode ser usado com valores negativos, para pegar elementos a partir do último para baixo:

```
$( "body div" ).eq(-2); // pega o penúltimo
$( "body div" ).eq(-1); // pega o último
```

ou

```
$( "body div:eq(-1)" ); // pega o último
```

*Nota:* Nem `:last` nem `:eq` são seletores CSS, só funcionam no jQuery.